# how to parse the error from web request

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

here is my code api response for error:

```
 guard (error == nil) else {
     print("There was an error with your request: \(error)")
     return
 }
```

response error:

> Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out." UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7f90d551ce50 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1001 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://xxxxx.ie/service/delivery/login, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://xxxxx.ie/service/delivery/login, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-2102, NSLocalizedDescription=The request timed out.})

how can get "The request timed out" and code to send user alert.

*Note please share, what is best practice what is best practice for error and generate human readable message.*

Comment: try after some time and check your internet connectivity .

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya yea the issue arise internet connectivity .. so i need to notify user the check internet connectivity

Comment: `NSError` has `code` property and `userInfo` dictionary including the localized description.

Comment: ya just notify user try again or check internet connectivity in alert or something else

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya sound! but sometime error not for net connection

Comment: @vadian could you make a answer for me . please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSError` has `code` and `localizedDescription` property. You can simply extract the information for example:

```
guard error == nil else {
    let code = error!.code
    let localizedDescription = error!.localizedDescription
    print(error!.userInfo) // here you can see what the userInfo dictionary contains
    let alertMessage = "An error with code \(code) occurred. Description: \(localizedDescription)"
    print(alertMessage)
    // or create an alert view controller to display the error message
    return
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the provided error is of type `Error` (was: `NSError` in Swift 2) and then access it's members, or the `userInfo`:

```
guard (error == nil) else {
    if let err = error as Error {
        let description = err.localizedDescription
        print("Error: \(description)"
    } else {
        // should not be reached at all, just to make sure we handle everything
        print("There was an error with your request: \(error)")
    }
     return
}
```

See: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nserror